# Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by instanceof Entrypoint instead

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, npm, webpack

I'm getting this error when I run the script `npm run watch`

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress  --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> i ｢webpack｣: Watching enabled \ Building Modules
>   (16%)C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824
>                   throw new Error(
>                   ^
>
> Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.groupsIterable and filter by
>   instanceof Entrypoint instead
>       at Chunk.get (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\webpack\lib\Chunk.js:824:9)
>       at C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:176:48
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\laravel-mix\node_modules\extract-text-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:171:18
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :12:1)
>       at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook [as _callAsync] (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:35:21)
>       at Compilation.seal (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1203:27)
>       at hooks.make.callAsync.err (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:547:17)
>       at _err0 (eval at create (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:24:12),
>   :11:1)
>       at _addModuleChain (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:1054:12)
>       at processModuleDependencies.err (C:\xampp\htdocs\VidhiStage\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:980:9)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:172:11) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! VidhiStage@1.0.0
>   watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development
>   node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress 
>   --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the VidhiStage@1.0.0 watch
>   script. npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
>   likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\BIKI
>   MALLIK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-08-02T08_45_14_967Z-debug.log

Following is the `Webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
  watch : true,
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    main : "./Components/Admin/Admin.js",
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname+'/public/js/build',
    filename : "Admin.js",
    chunkFilename: 'chunk/[name].[chunkhash].js',
    publicPath:'./js/build/'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue: 'vue/dist/vue.js',
      lolly : 'quill/dist/quill.min.js'
    }
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.styl$/,
        loader: 'css-loader!stylus-loader?paths=node_modules/bootstrap-stylus/stylus/',
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },  
  plugins: [
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the configuration from **webpack.config.js** file?

Comment: plz find in description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webpack version might be higher than 4.0.0. The plugin **extract-text-webpack-plugin** is not modified to be compatible with webpack > 4.0.0. So in the meantime use the version Webpack 4.

```
npm install --save-dev webpack@4.0.0
```

Comment: After this , i again run the script "npm run watch". it is asking to install webpack-cli . I installed that one also. but after installing that , i am getting the same issue as the first one. so how can i manage that?

Answer (score 0):

npm uninstall mini-css-extract-plugin , and use webpack 3.1.2 , this should done the job and install webpack-cli :)

Answer (score 0):

You could also upgrade the plugin:

```
npm install extract-text-webpack-plugin@next --save-dev
```